# Pymongo: How to terminate long running operation?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I submitted a fairly large ~300k operations BulkUpdate to a mongo database via a Python process.

The operations include fairly complicated array lookup and replacement. It takes way too long. like 1000 operations per hour.

I want to kill the entire thing. I already ran `db.current_op()`to get the operations and figured out the operation id. How do I kill the operation via Pymongo?

Please note that I have terminated the python script obviously, but the MongoDB is still processing the updates.

Comment: Did you try `CTRL+C`?

Comment: @rdas could you elaborate?

Comment: `CTRL+C` sends a process the `TERM` (termination signal)

Comment: @rdas Yea, I know, but the operation is running on the database. My script has since long stopped running.

Comment: Ah sorry I assumed the process was stuck or something.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/